# How to resize a responsive sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I don't know how to pull the right side of the sidebar in so that it will be flush with the right side of the top nav. This is a responsive site I'm building and don't think setting a width would be the right thing to do. Using bootstrap.

If someone has any suggestions I would appreciate it. Thanks

http://skeeterz71.com/auto/

T

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on line 100

```
<div class="navbar-inner>
    <div class="container">
```

should be

```
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
```

just missing some quotes there. The sidebar fits better than it did before, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Now I'm really confused. I added the ending " to navbar-inner and now my navbar is messed up and the sidebar drops to the bottom of the page.

Comment: There are still typos present in the code. The one above and on line 273 `<div class="span8 id="content">` should be `<div class="span8"  id="content">`. Also, try adding the `row` class to your `navbar-inner` div.

Comment: I ended removing the offending tag on line 100. If I put the missing quote in, it would drop my sidebar to the bottom of the page. I couldn't find the one you mentioned on line 273. I still have my original problem with the sidebar width. Thank you for pointing out the html. I did upload the edits.